# Making pie chart with top 5 values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to know how do I put this "a" with top 5 values into my pie chart. I could not find it anywhere in the internet and sadly couldn't figure it out myself neither

```
a <- c(straty$Martwi.jako.procent.populacji.przedwojennej)
  tail(sort(a),5)

  output$wykres6 <- renderPlot({ #tak tworzysz wykresy w shiny podajesz funkcji informacje o wyrenderowanym plocie i zapisujesz je pod dana nazwa w output
    ggplot(straty,aes(x="", y=Martwi.jako.procent.populacji.przedwojennej, fill=Martwi.jako.procent.populacji.przedwojennej))+
      geom_col(fill= rainbow(33)) +
      geom_text(aes(label = paste(Panstwo, ": ", Martwi.jako.procent.populacji.przedwojennej)),
                position = position_stack(vjust = .5)) +
      coord_polar(theta = "y") +
      theme_void()
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `tidyverse` package you can first arrange your values, get the top five using the `head` function and then create a pie chart using the `coord_polar` function after you create a bar chart.

```
subject <- c("Dan", "Tom", "Kim", "Sandra", "Bob", "Martha", "Tony", "Kelly", "Arnold", "Amanda")
value <- c(20, 50, 3, 66, 10, 100, 4, 23, 7.4, 44)
df <- data.frame(subject, value)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    arrange(desc(value)) %>%
    head(5) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = "", y = value, fill = subject)) +
    geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
    coord_polar("y", start = 0)
```